# How to store the date in dd/MM/yyyy in sql server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, date

Here this is my code

```
DateTime datetime = DateTime.Today;
labelDate.Text = datetime.ToString("'dd'/'MM'/'yyyy");
DateTime d = datetime;

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString= @"data source = desktop-u9dun78\sqlexpress;database = Al_Yousuf_Db;integrated security=SSPI";
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO StockEntryTB(Date,Product_No,Product_Name,Quantity,Original_Cost,Selling_Cost)VALUES('" + d + "'," + textBoxProdNo.Text + ",'" + textBoxProdName.Text + "','" + textBoxQuantity.Text + "'," + textBoxOriginalCost.Text + "," + textBoxSellingCost.Text + ")", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

But its stored the date in `yyyy/dd/MM` format. like `2016-06-11`(2016/june/11), but I want to store like `11/06/2016`.

Comment: You should never try to store dates in certain format. The database has date type which is to be used, then you show the format you want in the UI.

Comment: 1) Consider using a datetime type on your table definition instead of a varchar() type.  2) I recommend using a stored procedure for data base calls instead of a string built with user input.  3) If you want a particular format I suggest doing the formatting when the data is displayed.

Answer (score 8):

### Stop that!

You have a [bad habit to kick as choosing the wrong data](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) type in your SQL Server. You should *never* store your `DateTime` values as a `string`.

In SQL Server, `datetime` values stored as a binary. You can see some of format that just SQL Server shows you. But under the hood, it doesn't have *any* implicit format.

That's why, you should insert as a DateTime to your database and get DateTime values from your database. "Format" concept *only* applies when you *textual* (string) representation of that DateTime values.

Instead;

- Define your `Date` column as [`datetime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) or [`datetime2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) type.
- Insert your `DateTime` value *directly* with a [parameterized query](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) instead of a string.

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.140).aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.

As a last thing, `Date` might be a [reserved keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in future SQL Server versions, you *might* wanna use it as `[Date]` instead. But as a better solution, change your column name to *non*-reserved word.

Comment: thanks, tell me how to store in the format which i want with code

Comment: @John Again, you should **not** store them in _any_ format. Just store them as a `DateTime`. "Format" concept only applies when you get their string representation.

Answer (score 0):

You can format your date after retrieving from database.
C#:. String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dt); 
Where dt is the Datetime type variable containing your date you want to format.